# ggplot2 geom_errorbar in reshaped data

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the data.frame appended I would like to trend device sensitivity at 2 distances with measurement t date, facetted by monitor. This is pretty straightforward in `ggplot2`. First melt the data usinge the `reshape2` package

```
data.melt <- melt(big_df[,c(1:3,6)],id=c("Date","Monitor"))
```

then use ggplot2

```
ggplot(data.melt, aes(x=Date, y=value, col=variable)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Monitor)
```

I would also like to add geom_errorbar to these points. The problem I have is the error bars differ for the 50cm and 100cm measurements and I am unsure how to define the limits. i.e if `variable = Sensitivity.100cm` set the limits to `value+/-Error.100cm` and for `variable = Sensitivity.50cm` `limits = value+/-Error.50cm`. How can I best approach this task?

```
structure(list(Date = c("18/10/2012", "19/10/2012", "22/10/2012", 
"23/10/2012", "23/10/2012", "26/10/2012", "29/10/2012", "31/10/2012", 
"11/01/2012", "11/02/2012", "11/06/2012", "11/08/2012", "11/09/2012", 
"20/11/2012", "27/11/2012", "18/12/2012", "14/01/2012", "23/01/2013", 
"18/01/2013", "16/02/2013", "23/04/2013", "30/04/2013", "07/05/2013", 
"14/05/2013", "21/05/2013", "17/10/2012", "18/10/2012", "19/10/2012", 
"22/10/2012", "23/10/2012", "24/10/2012", "26/10/2012", "29/10/2012", 
"31/10/2012", "11/01/2012", "11/02/2012", "11/06/2012", "11/08/2012", 
"11/09/2012", "20/11/2012", "27/11/2012", "18/12/2012", "14/01/2013", 
"23/01/2013", "18/02/2013", "16/02/2013", "14/04/2013", "30/04/2013", 
"07/05/2013", "14/05/2013", "21/05/2013", "16/10/2012", "18/10/2012", 
"19/10/2012", "22/10/2012", "23/10/2012", "24/10/2012", "26/10/2012", 
"29/10/2012", "31/10/2012", "31/10/2012", "01/11/2012", "02/11/2012", 
"06/11/2012", "08/11/2012", "09/11/2012", "20/11/2012", "27/11/2012", 
"18/12/2012", "14/01/2013", "23/01/2013", "18/02/2013", "16/04/2013", 
"23/04/2013", "30/04/2013", "07/05/2013", "14/05/2013", "21/05/2013", 
"16/04/2013", "23/04/2013", "30/04/2013", "07/05/2013", "14/05/2013", 
"21/05/2013", "16/04/2013", "23/04/2013", "30/04/2013", "07/05/2013", 
"14/05/2013", "21/05/2013"), Sensitivity.100cm = c(23.9310344827586, 
23.6792452830189, 23.0708661417323, 23.75, 31.3333333333333, 
25.1351351351351, 25.9770114942529, 24.5192307692308, 25.4347826086957, 
22.987012987013, 23.1451612903226, 22.4822695035461, 23.4375, 
23.9495798319328, 23.5245901639344, 24.041095890411, 25.4198473282443, 
23.9097744360902, 25.8536585365854, 26.1940298507463, 28.0794701986755, 
26.4041095890411, 24.3875968992248, 24.7019867549669, 26.4383561643836, 
21.2328767123288, 23.5172413793103, 24.0566037735849, 30.7874015748032, 
23.1111111111111, 29.5, 23.0405405405405, 26.2068965517241, 25, 
24.3478260869565, 23.5064935064935, 22.0161290322581, 23.468085106383, 
22.8125, 25.3781512605042, 22.2131147540984, 24.7945205479452, 
23.6923076923077, 24.1353383458647, 25.2439024390244, 26.9402985074627, 
27.9470198675497, 23.8835616438356, 25.3798449612403, 25.0331125827815, 
25.7534246575342, 31.1627906976744, 30.6896551724138, 28.7735849056604, 
29.7637795275591, 28.5294117647059, 40, 29.7972972972973, 33.448275862069, 
33.4653465346535, 33.4653465346535, 36.9565217391304, 31.4285714285714, 
30.8870967741935, 28.5106382978723, 29.0625, 29.4117647058824, 
31.3934426229508, 33.5616438356164, 29.0151515151515, 30.8270676691729, 
29.6341463414634, 34.3283582089552, 32.7152317880795, 37.2602739726027, 
38.2945736434108, 35.8940397350993, 33.5616438356164, 40.5223880597015, 
36.0264900662252, 33.8356164383562, 34.4186046511628, 36.158940397351, 
33.7671232876712, 36.7910447761194, 36.0264900662252, 33.8356164383562, 
30.5426356589147, 36.158940397351, 33.7671232876712), Sensitivity.50cm = c(89.448275862069, 
89.4339622641509, 88.0314960629921, 88.4558823529412, 94.6666666666667, 
85.9459459459459, 92.2988505747126, 93.6538461538461, 91.5217391304348, 
88.2467532467532, 98.1451612903226, 85.6028368794326, 88.28125, 
90, 85.655737704918, 87.7397260273973, 88.7786259541985, 90.8270676691729, 
92.1341463414634, 89.6268656716418, 96.6887417218543, 91.1986301369863, 
89.7364341085271, 87.0198675496689, 90.4794520547945, 80.8219178082192, 
83.8620689655172, 85.188679245283, 82.992125984252, 88.1481481481482, 
93.3333333333333, 87.9054054054054, 90.6896551724138, 89.3269230769231, 
89.1304347826087, 90.1298701298701, 82.9032258064516, 82.6879432624114, 
87.265625, 88.8235294117647, 87.7868852459016, 90.5479452054795, 
91.7692307692308, 83.5338345864662, 92.0121951219512, 94.1044776119403, 
88.0132450331126, 90.8013698630137, 89.7984496124031, 87.6158940397351, 
88.2191780821918, 116.434108527132, 110, 116.509433962264, 112.44094488189, 
110.147058823529, 123.333333333333, 107.5, 119.655172413793, 
127.524752475248, 127.524752475248, 118.478260869565, 96.3636363636364, 
112.338709677419, 105.815602836879, 116.5625, 116.806722689076, 
118.27868852459, 129.452054794521, 113.106060606061, 115.789473684211, 
115, 133.582089552239, 132.05298013245, 136.575342465753, 154.573643410853, 
118.675496688742, 122.602739726027, 133.805970149254, 132.05298013245, 
136.575342465753, 154.573643410853, 132.185430463576, 136.506849315069, 
133.805970149254, 132.05298013245, 136.575342465753, 154.573643410853, 
132.185430463576, 136.506849315069), Error.100cm = c(1.3139695781557, 
1.56444565582802, 1.40192864683188, 1.36970117722038, 1.67497927018681, 
1.33092672997245, 1.78068199825628, 1.60608587389328, 1.71862916313499, 
1.29219147676184, 1.40378186980074, 1.29420479368047, 1.39754248593737, 
1.46276430130498, 1.42679468733846, 1.31571045974648, 1.42197984810665, 
1.39046932397796, 1.30208271366236, 1.4335352770372, 1.39230437361779, 
1.37754694254238, 1.41544528946403, 1.3095178763765, 1.37669529056451, 
1.81215843223602, 1.30671002217217, 1.60377358490566, 1.7304929902233, 
1.34969386357693, 1.63724022536571, 1.28022265685787, 1.79545969561073, 
1.60896158948861, 1.69788036432753, 1.30840530387077, 1.36621567307237, 
1.32512183966048, 1.37108818553002, 1.49853399160731, 1.39344262295082, 
1.33165904761805, 1.38033526499434, 1.40462719490747, 1.28772634645993, 
1.45283002492028, 1.38599003552691, 1.31267619160706, 1.44319351564034, 
1.32118790352715, 1.35955022200543, 1.5848874651365, 1.47108475915183, 
1.72669860544558, 1.61753059717907, 1.49248405369003, 1.86338998124982, 
1.44758684362355, 2.02050526795942, 1.88379184063767, 1.88379184063767, 
2.06235499576199, 1.47504112877929, 1.60684345525575, 1.45000342555042, 
1.53888403153064, 1.61641882871188, 1.63318515124355, 1.54679312200496, 
1.50945900342207, 1.55913092882163, 1.38241268887252, 1.63499270897065, 
1.48969826214596, 1.61504467432214, 1.74375533010884, 1.56437242530036, 
1.54679312200496, 1.76125727182178, 1.56156637384789, 1.54071532591808, 
1.65536096930718, 1.55875527098541, 1.54223702043804, 1.68034779838772, 
1.56156637384789, 1.54071532591808, 1.56197222322557, 1.55875527098541, 
1.54223702043804), Error.50cm = c(2.49898909406806, 2.94121835247545, 
2.66090476357729, 2.57562939531426, 2.84312035153866, 2.42491330336843, 
3.28542665010493, 3.03760942287141, 3.183873590408, 2.43051523015752, 
2.83178223646443, 2.48024233333982, 2.64934764965831, 2.77310924369748, 
2.66991761883645, 2.46860565629316, 2.61888806082572, 2.63908703380214, 
2.39518528553687, 2.6055358582233, 2.54601096513127, 2.51706504452232, 
2.65881302492679, 2.41699173389333, 2.50632526897698, 3.38331206444616, 
2.42264387175866, 2.88777884245547, 2.66556076847414, 2.57667068606312, 
2.82842712474619, 2.45392159423444, 3.26120941588761, 2.96210034629795, 
3.15029929264988, 2.45725817252266, 2.60322780509177, 2.44047901652299, 
2.62969260620419, 2.75266207632928, 2.70491803278689, 2.50538919974957, 
2.67245427169849, 2.53752436551672, 2.39363249102323, 2.66888876749965, 
2.42875772462149, 2.51128061073898, 2.6601687552902, 2.42695128500777, 
2.47524808213598, 3.02027282771754, 2.76292767227726, 3.35536212146769, 
3.02099623515762, 2.86858958869576, 3.22748612183951, 2.71029339461238, 
3.74049197592482, 3.5862911438168, 3.5862911438168, 3.62137635846906, 
2.52830160180932, 3.02499989250178, 2.75411175020533, 3.03382622483556, 
3.15545938748212, 3.12874339081841, 2.99339361416605, 2.94091650663359, 
2.96968686588444, 2.66763937246675, 3.1749324456989, 2.96611863265678, 
3.06769803788475, 3.47196832194708, 2.81593266562507, 2.91397909399762, 
3.17230019504959, 2.96611863265678, 3.06769803788475, 3.47196832194708, 
2.96463964047674, 3.06846257323317, 3.17230019504959, 2.96611863265678, 
3.06769803788475, 3.47196832194708, 2.96463964047674, 3.06846257323317
), Monitor = c("Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", 
"Berthold Red", "Berthold Red", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", "Berthold Blue", 
"NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", 
"NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", 
"NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", 
"NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "NC 61", "Mini Red", 
"Mini Red", "Mini Red", "Mini Red", "Mini Red", "Mini Red", "Mini Blue", 
"Mini Blue", "Mini Blue", "Mini Blue", "Mini Blue", "Mini Blue"
)), .Names = c("Date", "Sensitivity.100cm", "Sensitivity.50cm", 
"Error.100cm", "Error.50cm", "Monitor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
90L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
data.melt <- melt(big_df[,c(1:3,6)],id=c("Date","Monitor"))
data.melt2 <- melt(big_df[,c(1,4:6)],id=c("Date","Monitor"))

levels(data.melt2$variable) <- levels(data.melt$variable)

data.melt <- merge(data.melt,data.melt2,by=c("Date","Monitor","variable"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.melt, aes(x=Date, y=value.x, col=variable)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value.x-value.y,ymax=value.x+value.y)) +
  facet_wrap(~Monitor)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. When I try to format the x-axis by date `+ scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%b %Y"))` I get the error message `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`. I had already set Date to date class earlier on `big_df$Date <- strftime(strptime(big_df$Date,"%Y-%m-%d"),"%d/%m/%Y")`. Any ideas?

Comment: `strftime` returns a character vector not a date. `strptime` returns a POSIXlt vector. `as.Date` returns an object of class Date.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make two melted data frames - one for values other for errors. In second `melt()` function changed `value.name=` to `value2` to have different names.

```
data.melt1 <- melt(big_df[,c(1:3,6)],id=c("Date","Monitor"))
data.melt2 <- melt(big_df[,c(1,4,5,6)],id=c("Date","Monitor"),value.name="value2")
```

Now put together first data frame with `value2` column of second data frame.

```
data.tog<-cbind(data.melt1,data.melt2["value2"])

head(data.tog)
        Date      Monitor          variable    value   value2
1 18/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 23.93103 1.313970
2 19/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 23.67925 1.564446
3 22/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 23.07087 1.401929
4 23/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 23.75000 1.369701
5 23/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 31.33333 1.674979
6 26/10/2012 Berthold Red Sensitivity.100cm 25.13514 1.330927
```

In `geom_errorbar()` use `value+value2` and `value-value2` to set `ymax` and `ymin`.

```
ggplot(data.tog, aes(x=Date, y=value, col=variable)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-value2,ymax=value+value2))+facet_wrap(~Monitor)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `cbind` here, because the sorting of the melted data.frames is different.

Comment: @Roland First two columns are identical for both data frames and variables are in the same order - first 100 then 50.

Comment: Strangely that's not the case for me.